# SSE: unable to update stream when some new entity is created

Tags: nestjs, server-sent-events

Yo! I have written an SSE service in my nestjs app which looks like this (don't beat me I'm doing it for the first time):

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
export class SseService {
  private readonly _observables = new Map<string, Subject<string>>();

  getObservablesByIds(ids: string[]): Observable<string> {
    const observables: Observable<string>[] = []
    let observable;
    for (const id of ids) {
      observable = this._observables.get(id)
      if (!observable) {
        observable = new Subject<string>()
        this._observables.set(id, observable);
      }
      observables.push(observable);
    }
    return merge(...observables).pipe();
  }

  emit(id: string, action: string, data: unknown): void {
    const observable = this._observables.get(id);
    if (observable) {
      observable.next(JSON.stringify({ [action]: data }))
    }
  }
}
```

***This is how it works:*** there are many entities in the app which updates will me observed. I create an rxjs Subject for each entity and map it in the '_observables'.

Let's say this is a blog and I will send SSE when updating posts.

What methods do:

1. Emit sends a notification when something happens;
2. getObservablesByIds - pass id's of entities you wish to subscribe to and it will start streaming data. You hit `GET '/stream'` to invoke this mwethod.;

***The problem:***
Let's say I create a post:

```
const res = this.postsService.create()
this.sseService.emit(res.id, 'created', res)
```

Right now this 'emit' goes into nowhere - nobody has subscribed to this new entity events. That's actually ok - you can't subscribe to something that doesn't exist.

I (as a creator) cat hit `GET /stream` once again, passing now an id of a new entity to get updates.
But the rest of people who are watching the blog will not subscribe - they have no idea a new post was created and they don't have an id to subscribe to.

The second part of the problem is that I might need to filter SSE events in case some users can have restrictions (like they can't see updates of private posts). I don't know how to actually.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a `TRANSIENT` scope? I have a feeling that's where the error is coming from